# S3Client PHP SDK: Object of class <class> could not be converted to string

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get the following errors when I try to use the AWS PHP SDK:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'client.backoff' in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws_test_local\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3\S3Client.php on line 172

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\BackoffPlugin could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws_test_local\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3\S3Client.php on line 172

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'signature' in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws_test_local\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3\S3Client.php on line 175

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Aws\S3\S3Signature could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws_test_local\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3\S3Client.php on line 175
```

They originate from the following code inside the S3Client.php file part of the AWS SDK.

```
public static function factory($config = array())
{
    $exceptionParser = new S3ExceptionParser();

    // Configure the custom exponential backoff plugin for retrying S3 specific errors
    if (!isset($config[Options::BACKOFF])) {
        $config[Options::BACKOFF] = static::createBackoffPlugin($exceptionParser);
    }

    $config[Options::SIGNATURE] = $signature = static::createSignature($config);
...
```

The `Options`-class is the `Aws\Common\Enum\ClientOptions`. If you look at it it defines a lot of constants like this:

```
const SIGNATURE = 'signature';
const BACKOFF = 'client.backoff';
```

I call the factory function in the following way:

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/aws/aws-config.php');
```

My aws-config.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

    return array(
        'includes' => array('_aws'),
        'services' => array(
            'default_settings' => array(
                'params' => array(
                    'key'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'region' => 'eu-west-1'
                )
            )
        )
    );

?>
```

Any ideas? I installed the PHP SDK with Composer, so I'd expect any dependancies to be installed.

Comment: The argument to `S3Client::factory()` is supposed to be an array, not a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `S3Client::factory()` is supposed to be an array. You're giving it a filename that contains PHP code to return the array, but `S3Client` doesn't run the file. Try changing the file to:

```
<?php

    $s3options = array(
        'includes' => array('_aws'),
        'services' => array(
            'default_settings' => array(
                'params' => array(
                    'key'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
                    'region' => 'eu-west-1'
                )
            )
        )
    );

?>
```

Then your main program can do:

```
require(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/aws/aws-config.php');
$s3 = S3Client::factory($s3options);
```

Comment: You seem to be right, but in the documentation they write it just as I did in my example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/quick-start.html#service-builder

Comment: The only example like that is `AWS::factory`, not `S3Client::factory`.